# What function to use when you want both side effect and retain value in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

People are saying avoid using `map` to perform side effects over sequence and it makes sense.

But in the real world, I find myself needing to both retain the result and have the `map` evaluated eagerly, i.e, when inserting to db and returning the record.

Is `(doall (map ..))` my only choice here? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Could you add more detail about your DB use-case? It seems the main question here is one of naming & documentation of your function. Also, whether your function should operate on just 1 value or all values simultaneously to reduce DB round-trips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `(doall (map ..))`as you stated since it is clear what the intention is in your code. `mapv` works as well, although the intention is a little more ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

No. `(doall (map ..))` is not your only choice: `mapv` is not lazy, so it effectively does `(doall (map ..))`, but in one operation.

It is not great to use either `map` or `mapv` with a *map function* that produces side effects. Instead try to use `doseq`, which clearly indicates that side effects will be taking place. As you point out, and this goes to the crux of your question, the problem with `doseq` is that return results are not gathered together for you in a sequence as they are with `map` or `mapv`.

If you don't want a lazy sequence then try not to produce it in the first place, rather than producing it and then forcing it to be realised as you are currently doing. Thus we should rule out the use of `map`.

Most cases where you do not need laziness are covered by using `mapv` when your *map function* is not side-effecting, or `doseq` when it is, but doesn't return a result.

If your *map function* both produces a result, and is side effecting, and you want those results to be gathered together, then your best bet would be to use `mapv` over a *map function* that is named as clearly producing a side effect by having a name ending in `!`. While this is not a great use of `mapv`, at least the `!` clearly highlights what is going on.

Comment: so in my case, I'm doing db operation, where the function update and returns record at once.  If I want to separate them, I would have to first do the update, which is side-effects, then do another round trip to db to fetch them, which is pure. I'm not sure this is a good design.

Comment: @LoveProgramming Both updating and fetching are side-effecting (I/O of any kind precludes referential transparency), so doing it in two stages would not preserve any purity.

Comment: so what would you suggest in this case? i can not use doseq as I eventually need the fetched values.